# How can I webscrape a Wikipedia table with lists of data instead of rows?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from the Localities table located on the Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Districts_of_Warsaw page.

I would like to collect this data and put it into a dataframe with two columns ["Districts"] and ["Neighbourhoods"].

My code so far looks like this:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Districts_of_Warsaw"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html")

table = soup.find_all('table')[2]

A=[]
B=[]

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    cells=row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells)==2:
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))

df=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Neighbourhood'])
df['District']=B
print(df)
```

This gives the following dataframe:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgtVj.png)

Certainly, scraping the Neighbourhood column is not right since they are contained in lists, but I don't know how it should be done so will be glad for any tips.

In addition to it, I will appreciate any hints why scraping gives me only 10 districts instead of 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are scraping the right table? I understood that you need a second table with 18 districts and listed neighbourhoods.

Also, I'm not sure how you want to have districts and neighbourhoods arranged in a DataFrame, I've set districts as columns and neighbourhoods as rows. You can change it as you want.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Districts_of_Warsaw"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find_all("table")[1]

def process_list(tr):
    result = []
    for td in tr.findAll("td"):
        result.append([x.string for x in td.findAll("li")])
    return result

districts = []
neighbourhoods = []
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    if row.find("ul"):
        neighbourhoods.extend(process_list(row))
    else:
        districts.extend([x.string.strip() for x in row.findAll("th")])

# Check and arrange as you wish
for i in range(len(districts)):
    print(f'District {districts[i]} has neighbourhoods: {", ".join(neighbourhoods[i])}')

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(districts)):
    df[districts[i]] = pd.Series(neighbourhoods[i])
```

Some tips:

- Use `element.string` to get the text from an element
- Use `string.strip()` to remove any leading (spaces at the beginning) and trailing (spaces at the end) characters (space is the default leading character to remove) i.e. to clean the text

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer with explanation. I had a bit different concept for this dataframe, but it would work if only I had a list of postal codes for each neighbourhood. Anyway, your option is a way better, thank you. Honestly, I am working with multiple tables on the same page for the first time and I'm not sure about the way they are indexed. I thought they are starting from 0, but some example on the net confused me a bit.

Comment: @Psychotron You're welcome. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that odd rows are the Districts and even rows are the Neighbourhoods to walk the odd rows and use `FindNext` to grab the neighbourhoods , from row below, whilst iterating the District columns within the odd rows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from itertools import zip_longest

soup = bs(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Districts_of_Warsaw').content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('h2:contains("Localities") ~ .wikitable') #isolate table of interest
results = []

for row in table.select('tr')[0::2]: #walk the odd rows
    for i in row.select('th'): #walk the districts
        r = list(zip_longest([i.text.strip()] , [i.text for i in row.findNext('tr').select('li')], fillvalue=i.text.strip())) # zip the current district to the list of neighbourhoods in row below. Fill with District name to get lists of equal length
        results.append(r)
        
results = [i for j in results for i in j] #flatten list of lists
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns= ['District','Neighbourhood'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, especially for the code for isolating the table I needed. I tried this approach first, but wasn't sure which parameters should be used with the select_one() method.